# Copy from a source pd dataframe, add one day, then use this newly created dataframe as the source and repeat this x number of time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Python and pandas and I have the following forecasting problem I wish to resolve.

I have the below as the source dataframe:

| SKU | Date | Open Stock | Daily Sales | Close Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 4/01/23 | 100 | -10 | 90 |

I would like to make a copy of this dataframe and add one day to it with a new open stock based on the previous close stock.

| SKU | Date | Open Stock | Daily Sales | Close Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 5/01/23 | 90 | -10 | 80 |

And then repeat this for X number of days so I end up with multiple dataframes, one for each different day.

| SKU | Date | Open Stock | Daily Sales | Close Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 6/01/23 | 80 | -10 | 70 |

| SKU | Date | Open Stock | Daily Sales | Close Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 7/01/23 | 70 | -10 | 60 |

| SKU | Date | Open Stock | Daily Sales | Close Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 8/01/23 | 60 | -10 | 50 |

Then I will add each dataframe to a list and do a pd.concat of the list to get a combined dataframe similar to below.

| SKU | Date | Open Stock | Daily Sales | Close Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 4/01/23 | 100 | -10 | 90 |
| AAA | 5/01/23 | 90 | -10 | 80 |
| AAA | 6/01/23 | 80 | -10 | 70 |
| AAA | 7/01/23 | 70 | -10 | 60 |
| AAA | 8/01/23 | 60 | -10 | 50 |

I have tried with a for loop, but this will just copy the same date data three times.

```
#Create an empty list to store all dataframes
df_list = []

for i in range(3):
    next_day_df = original_df.copy()

    #Add 1 day to the Date column
    next_day_df['Date'] = next_day_df['Date'] + pd.Timedelta("1 day")

    #Setting the new opening stock to be the previous closing stock
    next_day_df['OpenStock'] = original_df['CloseStock']

    # Create a new dataframe using the copy
    df_new = pd.DataFrame(next_day_df)

    # Append the copied dataframe to the list
    df_list.append(df_new)

result = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a MultiIndex with your SKU and Date data to reindex your original df:

```
sku = df['SKU'].unique()
end_date = '8/1/2023'
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([sku,pd.date_range(start=df['Date'].min(),end = end_date,freq = 'MS')],names = ['SKU','Date'])

df = (df.set_index(['SKU','Date'])
.reindex(idx)
.ffill()
.assign(**{'Close Stock':lambda x: x['Open Stock'].add(x['Daily Sales'].cumsum()),'Open Stock': lambda x: x['Open Stock'].add(x['Daily Sales'].cumsum().shift(),fill_value=0)})
.reset_index())

g = {e:f for e,(n,f) in enumerate(df.groupby(['SKU','Date']))}

g.get(0) #0 is the first df
```

Output:

```
   SKU       Date  Open Stock  Daily Sales  Close Stock
0  AAA 2023-04-01       100.0        -10.0         90.0
1  AAA 2023-05-01        80.0        -10.0         70.0
2  AAA 2023-06-01        60.0        -10.0         50.0
3  AAA 2023-07-01        40.0        -10.0         30.0
4  AAA 2023-08-01        20.0        -10.0         10.0
```